# Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null with scoped model on flutter

Tags: flutter, scoped-model

I'm trying to create a function using scoped model which there will be a favorite_border icon and when it's pressed changes to a favorite icon. Besides that an increment counter will show the number of likes from the firebase data to the viewer. I'm trying to use scoped model to make this function but I'm getting the error "Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null". Any Ideas on the issue?

```
class LikesModel extends Model {

DocumentSnapshot snapshot;

bool liked = false;

static LikesModel of(BuildContext context) =>
  ScopedModel.of<LikesModel>(context);


bool isLiked() {

 liked = true;
 notifyListeners();

}

void pressed(){
liked = !liked;
notifyListeners();
}

void changeLikes() {
Firestore.instance
    .collection(snapshot.documentID)
    .document(snapshot.documentID)
    .updateData({'likes': FieldValue.increment(liked ? 1 : -1)});
notifyListeners();
}
}

class LanchonetesContact extends StatefulWidget {

final DocumentSnapshot lanchonetes;

LanchonetesContact(this.lanchonetes);

@override
_LanchonetesContactState createState() => _LanchonetesContactState();
}

class _LanchonetesContactState extends State<LanchonetesContact> {


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
              child: Card(
                  elevation: 1.0,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 70.0,
                        width: 390.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              LikesModel.of(context).isLiked() ?       
                                Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                              color: LikesModel.of(context).isLiked() ?   
                              Colors.red : Colors.black,
                              size: 50.0,
                            ),

                            StreamBuilder(
                               stream: Firestore.instance
                               .collection('lanchonetes')
                               .document(widget.lanchonetes.documentID)
                               .snapshots(),
                               builder: (context, snapshot) => Text(
                               snapshot.data.data["likes"].toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0),
                                ) 
                            ),
                          ],
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        LikesModel.of(context).changeLikes();
                        LikesModel.of(context).pressed();

                      }

                  ))


          ),
```

Comment: Apart from State Management techniques, you can also just store the variable in your utmost parent Widget and pass the variable and the function to change it down to the children Widgets.

Comment: **isLiked** should be to check if liked == bool, not to update the liked to true, if  your goal is to update it rename function to updateLiked or setLiked to make it more clear

Comment: Could you tell us in which line is giving you the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand completely the goal of `isLiked()`, but it is not returning anything and is expected a bool to be returned

```dart
bool isLiked() {

 liked = true;
 notifyListeners();

}
```

This throws an error here in the code below, as `LikesModel.of(context).isLiked()` returns null and **a bool in a conditional operator (?:) cannot be null**

```
Icon(
   LikesModel.of(context).isLiked() ?       
    Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
    color: LikesModel.of(context).isLiked() ?   
      Colors.red : Colors.black,
    size: 50.0,
),
```

If you just want to check `liked` you should just do

`bool isLiked() => liked;`

or even cleaner

`bool get isLiked => liked;` //Probably it would be nicer to make `liked` private :_liked.

Comment: Thanks Jaime it worked, this checking was what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the core concept of state management, the default setState for a widget keeps the state only until the widget is disposed (Which happens on navigating in your case.) 
You need to have an app state instead of a widget state, Give a read to one of the various state management techniques i.e. BLOC, Redux, Provider etc. 
What these do is keep the state for the app, or for any widget I should say even when you dispose the widget or navigate.

Comment: Thanks @Yudhishthir, I’m trying with scoped model, I Could understood its concept but I still Have difficulties. I edited my question with my outcome.